# PDO drivers are installed, but connection test says otherwise

Tags: php, sql, pdo, database-connection, drivers

I'm trying to connect to my database using PDO drivers and as far as I know they are installed correctly. I have added the extensions to my php.ini file and the drivers are in the ext folder, I downloaded Microsoft drivers 3.0. PHPinfo() says pdo_sqlsrv drivers are enabled. I'm using a Windows server with iis. I have PHP 5.4 installed and using the non-thread safe drivers. What else could I be missing?

```
<?php

try{
$dbh = new pdo( 'sqlsrv=websvr\sqlwebdata:1433;dbname=xxxx',
                'xxxx',
                'xxxx',
                array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
die(json_encode(array('outcome' => true)));
}
catch(PDOException $ex){
  print "Error!: " . $ex->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
```

}

?>

Comment: did you edit both php.ini files?

Comment: @KeesSonnema I suppose not, which other one needs to be edited? Just add the extensions like in the php.ini file?

Comment: You have two php.ini files. one in your php folder and one in your apache folder. try that.

Comment: @KeesSonnema I'm using IIS, not apache.

Comment: Exactly what says the error message?

Comment: @VolkerK Error!: could not find driver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://docs.php.net/manual/de/pdo.construct.php says:

> PDO::__construct() ( string $dsn, ...
> [...]
> In general, a DSN consists of **the PDO driver name, followed by a colon,** followed by the PDO driver-specific connection syntax

try it with (edit: fixed Database= keyword)

```
new pdo( 'sqlsrv:Server=websvr\sqlwebdata,1433;Database=xxxx',
```

see also: http://php.net/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.connection

Comment: Error!: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: An invalid keyword 'dbname' was specified in the DSN string. I did have "sqlsrv:host=websvr...." but it said host was invalid as well.

Comment: changed dbname to database and that fixed it. Thanks!